# Bose-Einstein condensation in 3D

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, statistics, bose-einstein-condensate

I have read in many books that BEC takes place in momentum space and in only 3-dimensions. What is meant by this statement?

Comment: Computing BEC in 1, 2, and 3 dimensions: http://www.physics.ucla.edu/~biritz/Comps/Solutions/01S/01S-13v2.pdf

Comment: By the way: some excellent answers here - http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4976/

Comment: It is really helpful but what is meant by momentum space?Can BEC take place in higher dimensions as well??

Comment: The critical thing is the density of states in the limit E --> 0. Higher numbers of spatial dimensions are generally favorable for the occurence of BEC.

Comment: I have checked them already.They give almost the same answer as is in the link.

Comment: But the problem is that we know everything about 3D, if we talk of any higher dimension,then what does exactly it mean ? e.g 4 or 5D?